# Shopware 6 - Delete custom fields on plugin uninstall

Tags: plugins, service, shopware

I have created a custom service which creates custom fields in the customer form during plugin installation. When activating the plugin, the service runs correctly and performs the required function.

```
public function activate(ActivateContext $context): void
{
  ../
  $customFieldSetService = $this->container->get('custom.service');
  $customFieldSetService->extendCustomerFields();
  /..
}
```

When uninstalling the plugin, I get the error message: You have requested a non-existent service  "custom.service".

```
public function uninstall(UninstallContext $context): void
{
 ../
  $customFieldSetService = $this->container->get('custom.service');
  $customFieldSetService->deleteCustomerFields();
 /..
}
```

service.xml:

`<service id="custom.service" class="MyPlugin\Service\CustomFieldSetService" public="true" />`

How can I call my own service within the uninstall function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me quickly show you an example of how we're doing it.
The code should be self-explaining i guess :)

```
public function uninstall(UninstallContext $uninstallContext): void
    {
        if ($uninstallContext->keepUserData()) {
            parent::uninstall($uninstallContext);

            return;
        }

        $this->removeCustomField($uninstallContext);

        parent::uninstall($uninstallContext);
    }

private function removeCustomField(UninstallContext $uninstallContext)
    {
        $customFieldSetRepository = $this->container->get('custom_field_set.repository');

        $fieldIds = $this->customFieldsExist($uninstallContext->getContext());

        if ($fieldIds) {
            $customFieldSetRepository->delete(array_values($fieldIds->getData()), $uninstallContext->getContext());
        }
    }

private function customFieldsExist(Context $context): ?IdSearchResult
    {
        $customFieldSetRepository = $this->container->get('custom_field_set.repository');

        $criteria = new Criteria();
        $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsAnyFilter('name', ['your_custom_fieldset']));

        $ids = $customFieldSetRepository->searchIds($criteria, $context);

        return $ids->getTotal() > 0 ? $ids : null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have now set up my uninstall structurally like this. Of course I would have liked to outsource all functions that affect the custom fields in my own class, but unfortunately that does not seem to be possible.

Comment: You can. Take a look at our BlogPlugin for the update method for example: 
https://github.com/ChristopherDosin/Shopware-6-Blog-Plugin/blob/master/src/SasBlogModule.php#L87

Comment: But there still seems the limitation that the service container can not be used during uninstall (during update it might work), according to Valerii's answer, right?

Comment: In my particular case, creating a new object of the class and passing the service 'custom_field_set.repository' as a parameter for the constructor worked. However, I think that more complex nesting and dependencies of services might not be easy to implement in the uninstall function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call it as before uninstall your plugin is deactivated. As soon as it has been deactivated, all services from that plugin are deleted from the service container and can't be called. You can create an instance of your service directly in uninstall method. I think it is the best solution.